# generate or clone or redispatch TRUSTED (keyboard) event in typescript (or javascript)

Tags: javascript, events

I have made a logic which triggers in an editor (a third party module which I should not modify) a drop-down menu with intellisense suggestions by pressing space key. The thing is that the logic needs two keystrokes (or more) and performs some processing in between but I only want to press the space key once then use the mouse for further user actions. So I have to generate the consequent keystrokes. One of my idea was to clone/re-dispatch the first event but no matter what I have tried the resulting event has isTrusted == false and, although editor's event handler is triggered, the key is not written in the editor and drop-down not shown.

How to generate or clone or re-dispatch a trusted event?

Comment: Are you looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974262/how-to-clone-or-re-dispatch-dom-events or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060630/re-dispatch-keyboardevent @gigi

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar I would say the key element here is that I need a trusted event. I also found several posts about cloning an object but they either didn't work (the dispatch function told me is not an event) or didn't get me an event with isTrsuted true;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412590/sending-keyboard-events-programmatically-doesnt-dispatch-them-into-inputs read this answer.. SOrry but i can only suggest... @gigi